# How do I remove the bottom cell border line from entire row when clicking a shape?

Tags: excel, vba

I have shape that I use as a button.
When i click this button I can hide/unhide a range of rows bellow the button.
When I click this button I also want to have the bottom border line removed from the entire row where the button is placed.

This is my code.

```
    Sub ArrowClick()

    Dim r As Integer
    Dim r1 As Integer
    Dim r2 As Integer
    Dim sr1 As String
    Dim sr2 As String

    r = ActiveSheet.Shapes(Application.Caller).TopLeftCell.Row

    r1 = r + 1
    r2 = r + 9

    sr1 = CStr(r1)
    sr2 = CStr(r2)


    If ActiveSheet.Rows(sr1 & ":" & sr2).EntireRow.Hidden = True Then
        ActiveSheet.Rows(sr1 & ":" & sr2).Hidden = False
     
    ElseIf ActiveSheet.Rows(sr1 & ":" & sr2).Hidden = False Then
        ActiveSheet.Rows(sr1 & ":" & sr2).Hidden = True

    End If


    End Sub
```

I'm a beginner, so feel free to point out any improvments of my code.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: If you're not sure about the syntax for a certain operation in Excel, the best thing to do is record a macro while performing the task manually and see if that gives you what you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this:

```vb
Sub ArrowClick()
    With ActiveSheet.Shapes(Application.Caller).TopLeftCell.EntireRow
        .Borders(xlEdgeBottom).LineStyle = xlNone
        With .Offset(1, 0).Resize(9)
            .Hidden = Not .Hidden
        End With
    End With
End Sub
```

Getting comfortable using `Offset()` and `Resize()` will help you a lot when writing VBA in Excel.